# An example of a space built of two vertices and two edges which is homeomorphic to the simplicial circle but not a simplicial complex.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am being asked to build a space using two vertices and two edges so that space is homeomorphic to the simplicial circle, which always has three 0 and 1 simplicies and a Euler characteristic of 0, but it is not a simplicial complex.

So I'm assuming that violating the conditions that make a simplicial complex to create a space that is homeomorphic to the circle.

How would I go about this>

Comment: It will not be a simplicial complex, but a CW-complex. How would you go about it in real life, i.e. build a circle given two pieces of string?